# How to remove the etex warning when using cryptocode with the llncs document class?

Tags: warnings, e-tex, cryptocode

When using the `cryptocode` package along with the `llncs` document class, as provided by the [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-lecture-notes-in-computer-science/kzwwpvhwnvfj#.WtR5Hy5ua71), `etex` complains with the following warning:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use. etex.sty code will not be used. To force etex package to load, add \RequirePackage{etex} at the start of the document.
```

Here's a MWE to replicate the problem:

```latex
% This is samplepaper.tex, a sample chapter demonstrating the
% LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings;
% Version 2.20 of 2017/10/04
%
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}
    Dummy text.
\end{document}
```

I've also tried to remove the following lines in `llncs.cls`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{multicol} % needed for the list of participants, index
\RequirePackage{aliascnt}
```

which are the only occurences of `\RequirePackage` in the whole file. However, the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}
    Dummy text.
\end{document}
```

does not produce the aforementioned warning. Thus:

1. How important is this warning, how does it affect the final document?
2. Is it possible to identify which lines in `llncs.cls` conflict with `cryptocode` and to know how to somehow correct them?

Comment: the warning is harmless, but write the author of crytocode that he should no longer load it. It is quite unnecessary nowadays.

Comment: https://github.com/arnomi/cryptocode/issues/9

Comment: I've dropped the dependency and pushed a new version to CTAN. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ignore it, or ask the maintainer to remove etex, or silence the warning with

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@etex.sty\endcsname{}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
```